# How to fix Mac terminal being incredibly slow after brew install tmux

Tags: macos, unix, terminal, homebrew, tmux

I've installed tmux using brew ( arch -x86_64 brew install tmux ) on M1 Mac and since then my terminal is super slow. on lunch, after running commands and it's just incredibly slow.

I tried deleting the package using

```
brew uninstall pkg
```

it didn't work. I tried using the following commands as well.

```
brew remove pkg

brew rmtree tmux
```

I get "Error: tmux is not currently installed" since I've already uninstalled it..

and when using

```
sudo find / -name "*tmux*"
```

I still get many files including tmux.

GIFs showing the situation
[image]
[image]

any ideas/help on how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Ok I have fixed it.

although I didn't know exactly what was the problem but it was something related to **oh-my-zsh** and to be more specific it was with the current **oh-my-zsh** theme **powerlevel9k** after installing tmux.

**here is the steps I toke:**  I tried to change my shell to **bin/bash** it worked great. Tried a couple more shells and all worked great except **zsh**. then I tried to change the **.oh-my-zsh** directory name just for testing purposes and opened zsh, it worked great but of course without **oh-my-zsh**.

so I went to **.zshrc** and commented this line.

```
#ZSH_THEME="powerlevel9k/powerlevel9k"
```

obviously installing tmux messed things up so I'll need to reinstall the theme or oh-my-zsh all over again.